# how do devices identify the HDCP compliant version of the monitor?

Tags: public-key-encryption, hdmi, hdcp

I wonder how the hdcp compliant devices identify the version of the `HDCP like 1.4 or 2.2.`

Is it during the key share or after the authentication process.

Comment: this would depend on the operating system, and it's not a question about programming (maybe more suitable for superuser).